# Pygtk threading long command line process

Tags: python, command-line, pygtk, graphicsmagick

I am in PyGtk on Windows. My program converts PDF's to images using GraphicsMagick then displays the image. The conversion can be very long on multi-page PDF's so the program has to wait for the command line to return and I need to get around this and allow the user to use the GUI while the image is created. My attempts to use gtk's threading and python's threading have not worked so far, is there a way to easily call the GraphicsMagick conversion as a background process and returnot wait for it to return?

I am using subprocess(command) to perform the conversion from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use subprocess.Popen:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["command", "arg1", "arg2"])
```

For more information see:
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

If you really need to use threads use `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` before `gtk.main()`

http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/gdk-functions.html#function-gdk--threads-init

Comment: Thanks the answered my question. Unfortunately I did not ask the correct question because I realize the process I need to run in the background is more than just a command line call, its a loop that calls the command line n times for however many pages are in the PDF. Maybe a combination of subprocess.Popen and some other threading?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an idle function that calls `subprocess.Popen()` and returns `True` if there are still pages left to process. That means it will be called again at the next available opportunity. When you are finished with the pages, you can return `False` from the idle function and it will not be called anymore.